# Dynamically Update AblePlayer's (html5 video) Source

Tags: jquery, twig, html5-video

For my website, we need to dynamically update the source of AblePlayer depending on some user input. We're using a CMS, and in the CMS, the user puts in the File ID that we need. Then, with that ID, we make the ajax calls to the API we're using. The response to those ajax calls contains the information I need. Relevant code:

```
<video data-able-player
  id="a-player"
  preload="auto"
  data-youtube-id=""
  data-transcript-div="transcript"
  playsinline >
</video>
```

Then, in my JS file, I update the data-youtube-id attribute:

```
$("#a-player").attr("data-youtube-id", src_id);
```

Right now, I have it hooked to a button click for testing purposes. In production, I think it'll be on page load.

When I inspect the video element, the source updates like it should, but the video still doesn't play.

We're using twig for the templates, if that matters at all.

I know this is kind of a niche case, but I was wondering if anyone has run into similar problems and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone in the future runs across this same problem, we fixed it by setting up the fields differently on the Craft side. We set up the field to accept a custom entry that contains the VTT file, the language, and type (audio description, transcript, subtitles). Then, in the .twig file:

```
<video id="video-{{block.youtubeId}}" preload="auto"
      data-able-player
      data-transcript-div="able-transcript-{{block.youtubeId}}"
      data-youtube-id="{{block.youtubeId}}" >
       {% for resource in block.videoResources %} {# Resource entry itself #}
        {% for file in resource.initiativesResourceEntry %} {# File types #}
          {% for v in file.vttFile %} {# Actual file #}
            {% set req_url = siteUrl ~"file/get_file?path="~v.getUrl() %}
              <track kind="{{file.fileType}}" src="{{req_url}}" srclang="{{file.fileLang}}">
          {% endfor %} {# End actual file #}
        {% endfor %} {# End types #}
        {% endfor %} {# End resource entry loop #}
    </video>
```

It's a little ugly, but it works. It creates the video player, then adds as many files as it has as tracks. That way, a video could have audio description, captioning, subtitles, or any combination of the three in any supported language.

We're using Craft 2, so I don't know if it's a Craft 2 thing or not, but I couldn't access, for instance, `block.videoResources.initiativesResourceEntry` directly. I had to loop through each step, which is annoying, but hey it worked.